# linked list c++, overloading [], overall structure

Tags: c++, linked-list, overloading

Hello I wrote linked list and I'm looking for some advices, what shouldn't I do or what should I avoid or what can I do better, also I'm having trouble with overloading [] and I can't find solution.

I have declared:

```
    linked_list<int> *pointer=new linked_list<int>();
```

And filled it with some digits, then tried to reach them by:

```
    int something = pointer[0];
```

etc. It wasn't working, I got message:

```
    error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'linked_list<int>' to 'int'
```

I tried:

```
    int something = pointer->operator[](0);
```

and it worked. I don't know what is wrong. Can someone help me with that?

Rest of the code:

```
Node:

    template <typename variable_type>
    class node {
    private:
        variable_type object;
        node<variable_type> *next_node;

    public:
        node();
        node(const variable_type &new_object, node<variable_type> *new_next_node);
        ~node();
        void set_object(const variable_type &new_object);
        void set_next_node(node<variable_type> *new_next_node);
        variable_type &get_object();
        node<variable_type> *get_next_node();
       };

    #include "node.h"

    template<typename variable_type>
    node<variable_type>::node()
    {
        this->next_node = nullptr;
    }

    template<typename variable_type>
    node<variable_type>::node(const variable_type & new_object, 
        node<variable_type> * new_next_node)
    {
        this->object = new_object;
        this->next_node = new_next_node;
    }

    template<typename variable_type>
    node<variable_type>::~node()
    {
        //
    }

    template<typename variable_type>
    void node<variable_type>::set_object(const variable_type & new_object)
    {
        this->object = new_object;
    }

    template<typename variable_type>
    void node<variable_type>::set_next_node(node<variable_type> * new_next_node)
    {
        this->next_node = new_next_node;
    }

    template<typename variable_type>
    variable_type &node<variable_type>::get_object()
    {
        return this->object;
    }

    template<typename variable_type>
    node<variable_type> *node<variable_type>::get_next_node()
    {
        return this->next_node;
    }
```

linked_list:

```
#include "node.cpp"
    #include <iostream>

    template <typename variable_type2>
    class linked_list
    {
    protected:
        node <variable_type2> *head;
        int size;

    public:
    linked_list();
    ~linked_list();
    bool is_empty() const;
    int length() const;
    void insert(variable_type2 &new_object, const int index);
    variable_type2 &remove(const int index);
    void print() const;
    variable_type2 &operator[](const int index);
};

#include "linked_list.h"

template<typename variable_type2>
linked_list<variable_type2>::linked_list()
{
    this->head = nullptr;
    this->size = 0;
}

template<typename variable_type2>
linked_list<variable_type2>::~linked_list()
{
    if (!is_empty()) {
        do {
            node <variable_type2> *temp = this->head;
            this->head = temp->get_next_node();
            delete temp;
        } while (head);
    }
    this->size = 0;
}

template<typename variable_type2>
bool linked_list<variable_type2>::is_empty() const
{
    if (!this->head) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

template<typename variable_type2>
int linked_list<variable_type2>::length() const
{
    return this->size;
}

template<typename variable_type2>
void linked_list<variable_type2>::insert(variable_type2 &new_object, const int index)
{
    if (this->is_empty()) {
        node <variable_type2> *new_node = new node<variable_type2>(new_object, nullptr);
        this->head = new_node;
    }
    else if (index == 0) {
        node <variable_type2> *new_node = new node<variable_type2>(new_object, this->head);
        this->head = new_node;
    }
    else if (index <= this->length()) {
        node <variable_type2> *temp = this->head;

        for (int i = 1; i < index; ++i) {
            temp = temp->get_next_node();
        }

        node <variable_type2> *new_node = new node<variable_type2>(new_object, temp->get_next_node());
        temp->set_next_node(new_node);
    }
    else { //when index is out of range
        return;
    }

    ++(this->size);
}


template<typename variable_type2>
variable_type2 &linked_list<variable_type2>::remove(const int index)
{
    if (index == 0) {
        node <variable_type2> *node_to_remove = this->head;
        variable_type2 return_object = node_to_remove->get_object();
        this->head = this->head->get_next_node();

        delete node_to_remove;
        --(this->size);
        return return_object;

    }
    else if (index <= this->length()) {
        node <variable_type2> *temp = this->head;

        for (int i = 2; i < index; ++i) {
            temp = temp->get_next_node();
        }

        node <variable_type2> *node_to_remove = temp->get_next_node();
        temp->set_next_node(node_to_remove->get_next_node());
        variable_type2 return_object = node_to_remove->get_object();

        delete node_to_remove;
        --(this->size);
        return return_object;

    }
    else {
        //return;

}

template<typename variable_type2>
void linked_list<variable_type2>::print() const
{
    if (!is_empty()) {
        node <variable_type2> *temp = this->head;

        for (int i = 0; i < this->length(); ++i) {
            std::cout << temp->get_object() << " ";
            temp = temp->get_next_node();
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

template<typename variable_type2>
variable_type2 &linked_list<variable_type2>::operator[](const int index)
{
    if (!is_empty() && index < this->length()) {
        node <variable_type2> *temp = this->head;

        for (int i = 0; i < index; ++i) {
            temp = temp->get_next_node();
        }

        variable_type2 return_value = temp->get_object();
        return return_value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `(*pointer)[0]` instead. Operators don't work on pointers.

Comment: Your subscript operator is overloaded for an value of type `linked_list<T>`, you're trying to use it on a variable of type `linked_list<T> *` so of course it won't work. Like Rusty says, you need to dereference first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have

```
linked_list<int> *pointer=new linked_list<int>();
```

Which means `pointer` is an actual pointer.  A real pointer has an `operator[]` defined in the compiler, which performs pointer arithmetic and dereferences the result.  That means

```
int something = pointer[0];
```

is the same as

```
int something = *(pointer + 0);
```

which gives you a reference to the `linked_list<int>` you originally created, and you can't assign a `linked_list` to an `int`, like the error says.

When `pointer` is a pointer, `pointer[0]` does not call the `operator[]` that you have defined in your `linked_list` class.  To do that, you either have to use

```
int something = (*pointer)[0];
```

or

```
int something = pointer->operator[](0);
```

like you figured out.  Or, you could get rid of the pointer entirely and have

```
linked_list<int> list;
```

and then you can use it like

```
list.some_function_call();
int foo = list[some_index];
```